# React json schema form relations

Tags: javascript, json, forms, reactjs

From the step 1 dropdown if the user is picking one after submit redirect it to step2schema, and if he is picking two redirect him after submit to step3schema. Here is the jsfiddle (check my link):

```js
const Form = JSONSchemaForm.default;
const step1schema = {
  title: "Step 1",
  type: "number",
  enum: [1, 2],
  enumNames: ["one", "two"]
  
};
const step2schema = {
  title: "Step 2",
  type: "object",
  required: ["age"],
  properties: {
    age: {type: "integer"}
  }
};

const step3schema = {
  title: "Step 3",
  type: "object",
  required: ["number"],
  properties: {
    number: {type: "integer"}
  }
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {step: 1, formData: {}};
  }
  
  onSubmit = ({formData}) => {
   if (this.state.step === 1) {
      this.setState({
        step: 2,
        formData: {
          ...this.state.formData, 
          ...formData
        }, 
      });
    } else {
      alert("You submitted " + JSON.stringify(formData, null, 2));
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <Form 
        schema={this.state.step === 1 ? step1schema : step2schema}
        onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
        formData={this.state.formData}/>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-jsonschema-form@1.0.0/dist/react-jsonschema-form.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bogdanul11/sn4bnw9h/29/

Here is the lib I used for documentation: https://github.com/mozilla-services/react-jsonschema-form

What I need to change in order to have my desired behavoir ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your state to this first

```
this.state = {step: 0, formData: {}};
```

Then replace your `onSubmit` logic to

```
onSubmit = ({formData}) => {
  const submitted = formData;
    this.setState({
      step: submitted,
      formData: {
        ...this.state.formData, 
        ...formData
      }, 
  })
}
```

Finally replace your schema logic

```
schema={this.state.step === 0 ? step1schema : ( this.state.step === 1 ? step2schema : step3schema)}
```

the schema selecting ternary operation is what we call a compound ternary operation. If `state.step` is 0 , we select step1schema... if not a new selection statement `( this.state.step === 1 ? step2schema : step3schema)` is run; in which if step is 1, step2schema is selected and for anything else step3schema.

Lets say you have more than 3 schemas and you want to access them. For that you will have to define the schemas in an array and access them using the index.

```
schemaArray = [ {
    // schema1 here
} , {
    // schema2 here
} , {
    // schema3 here
}, {
   // schema4 here
}, {
   ....
}]
```

Now your schema selecting you will have to use

```
schema = { schemaArray[ this.state.step ] }
```

Comment: This works, thank you, one more think, can you explain to me how this schema={this.state.step === 0 ? step1schema : ( this.state.step === 1 ? step2schema : step3schema)}, works? I didn't quite get it, what if I would have more than 3 forms, for example 6, how I can organize them in that schema? Is there any documentation about it? Thank you!

Comment: Please look at the edited answer, I have added the explanation and code for your concern

Comment: I read your explications and tryed to apply all that, something is still not right, if you can, I posted this question since is a bit different from this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47197442/react-json-schema-rendering